# HTML Login and Sign in buttons don't work

Tags: html, button, href

I am creating a html website and am unsure as to why my login and sign in buttons don't work.

My Code:

```
    <div class="topnav">

    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png')}}" class='logo'> 
    <nav href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Log In</nav>
    <nav href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Sign up</nav>

    <div class="search-container">

        <form action=''>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.topnav {
background-color: #ca91be;
overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav nav {
float: right;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 50px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Help please!

Comment: What framework are you using? Flask?

Comment: As the answer below indicates, you're using the wrong element. Also, neither anchors nor nav elements are buttons. Details matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `<nav><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Log In</a></nav>`. Link elements are clickable, not nav elements.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: It's possible that there's JavaScript involved that has bindings to those elements. Likely? Probably not, but it's possible.